# Is infrabarrelled and quasibarrelled the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Am I right in saying that infrabarrelled and quasibarrelled is defined exactly the same way.
If so, which terminology is used most nowadays?

Comment: Not quite, according to wikipedia. infrabarrelled applies when the barrels themselves are bounded, while quasibarrelled applies when the barrels can absorb all bounded sets. They do not need to be bounded themselves. Possibly they could imply each other - I've never heard of the terms before - but the definitions themselves are different.

Comment: Yes, I agree that according to wikipedia it looks that way. But if you check the reference cited on the wikipedia article about infrabarrelled spaces you see that is not what is meant. The original source defines "a barrel absorbing all bounded sets in E (briefly, a bound absorbing barrel)", and then define infrabarrelled as "every bound absorbing barrel in E is a neighborhood of 0". In other words exactly like quasibarrelled is defined on wikipedia.

Comment: I think that both term are used synonymously but quasibarrelled is more common than infrabarrelled.